# Using nAnt to build projects containing EDMX

Tags: build-process, nant, edmx

I've been working on training myself in the ways of using nAnt over the past few days, and have stumbled across an issue.  During the development process, I've been using the new tools, like Entity Data Model, for database access.

When you go to try to build a library/executable that contains the Edmx product, you cannot embed the required files from visual studio.  Now, I realize that I can do an exec task inside of nAnt and call msbuild for the particular project file, but I am trying to keep this to be completely nAnt build for now, so I'm in a heavy struggle to get things to work.

I did some searching to find a way ot handle this, and came across this [Inline C# class](http://akutz.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/nant-and-processing-edmx-files/) that is supposed to do the trick.  My problem is that I do not see how you call this in the target stack in order to get it to do its job.  Can anyone shed some light on this?  It would be of some great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so I'm a bit further along with this.  I have since found that the code the gentleman has posted needs to be under the task for which it is meant to be run for.  I'm even getting the *.ssdl, *.csdl, and *.msl files rendering into the directory... cool beans.

nwo i'm getting something interesting coming through... I've got reference via a "references" tag to System.Data.Entity, but I keep getting the following compile error:

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK!!!

Got it!  I had to edit the NAnt.exe.config file and add the System.Data.Entity.dll file into the Framework element for the .net framework 3.5!!!

I may wind up building a 3.5 SP1 entry, and if someone can give me a good area to post it, I'd be good to go.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the ssdl, csdl and msl files to replicate in the resources, could you help me out?

Comment: Let me see if I can pull up the nAnt script tonight, and if so, I'll post it here... wound up being stupid simple once I got it as I recall.